# Show a spinner while uploading a file Django and Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have tried a variety of things from the internet I am not able to understand completely what they are doing.
What I'd like to do is I'd like to show a spinner while I'm uploading a file to amazon S3 cloud.
I have a table in which columns contain either text or files.
What I do is when the user clicks update I take all data from the particular row at which the update button was pressed and send the data to a python/django script to process the information and upload media files if given.

This part works fine but on the client side it looks pretty unresponsive as the browser shows nothing.
I want to show a spinner while this is happening and want to update the row data when the updated data is received from the server.
What would be the django code to send response to the ajax script instead of rendering the whole page and in what way can I access this data which maybe sent in as a dictionary object.

As for the progress bar

```
     $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
          $('#spinner').show(); 
          }).ajaxStop(function() {
          $('#spinner').hide();
     });
options{beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        success: showResponse
}
$('formid').ajaxsubmit(options);
```

Would this code work? This is by using the forms plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provide looks kind of messy, here are some corrections and explanations:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $('#spinner').show(); // show #spinner when ajax request starts
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#spinner').hide(); // hide #spinner when ajax request is completed
});

$('formid').ajaxsubmit({
    beforeSubmit: showRequest,
    success: showResponse    
}); // initialize the form submit
```

Hope this helps.